# How to CROSS COMPILE linux for ppc

Tags: embedded

I want to cross compile LINUX 2.6.26 Kernel for ppc

steps i used are

```
1. make arch=ppc menuconfig
2. make arch=ppc cross_compile=ppc_74xx-
```

while executing the second step I get

VDSO32 error.

I'm unable to remove that error,

actually I want to create a board support configuration file, but I'm unable to find proper notes for doing that.

kindly any one help me in the following.

1. Compiling linux kernel 2.6 for powerpc 7410 i.e MPC7410
2. Creating a board support for MPC7410 board
3. compiling linux kernel properly for powerpc or ppc.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember, right now, if 2.6.26 used ppc or powerpc, so I would try:

```
make menuconfig ARCH=powerpc CROSS_COMPILE=ppc_xyz-
```

As far as I know, there is no tutorial for doing that. I guess everyone just learns while doing.

[DENX](http://www.denx.de/wiki/ELDK-5/WebHome) provides a complete solution, with a toolchain, a bootloader, basic binaries, kernel and disk image building tools. I would suggest downloading their packages and using that at first.

Their mailing list is also a good place to ask more specific questions.

When I have to add support to a new board, I try to find one which uses the same processor and just replicate the files, changing names, options and functions as I go. It helps to have a development board that is already supported so you have a known good starting point.